# How to find the below fold target element without scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

What this script does is it looks for the target background image and once found, replaces the div of that background image with the new div. This works, however, if the targeted background image is below fold, you would need to scroll down to that spot and refresh the page before it takes effect. Is there a way for the script to work right away if the background image is below fold?

```
<script id="myhtml" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div>test</div>
</script>

<script language="javascript">

    (function($) {
        var insertdiv = {
            init: function() {

            $(".someclass").each(function() {
               var bgimage = $(this).css("background-image");

               var bgimagesize = [
                  "https://somewebsite.com/images/someimage-123456\\?&scl=1&wid=2544"
               ].join("|");

               var isImg = new RegExp("(" + bgimagesize + ")", "i");

               if (isImg.test(bgimage)) {
            $($("#myhtml").html()).insertAfter($(this));
            $(this).remove();
               }
              });

        $(function() {
          setTimeout(insertdiv.init(), 200); 
        });

    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: When you say "below the fold" do you mean that this content is in some scroll-able area that hasn't been rendered yet, or is the content just out of view? Judging by your issue, I feel like we're talking about dynamically created content "below the fold"

Comment: meaning the div to be replaced by a new div sits in an area of the page where you need to scroll down first before you can see it.